# Operation on pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know how to describe my problem in words, I just model it

Problem modeling:

Let say we have two dataframes df1, df2 with the same columns

**df1**

```
idx | col1 | col2 | col3 |  col4 
---------------------------------
 0  |  1   | -100 |   2  |  -100
```

**df2**

```
idx | col1 | col2 | col3 |  col4
---------------------------------
 0  |  12  |  23  |  34  |   45
```

Given these two df-s we get

**df_result**

```
idx | col1 | col2 | col3 |  col4 
---------------------------------
 0  |  1   |  23  |   2  |   45
```

I.e. we get `df1` where all `-100` substituted with values from `df2` accordingly.

Question: How can I do it **without for-loop**? In particular, is there an operation in pandas or on two lists of the same size that could do what we need?

PS: I can do it with for loop but it will be much slower.

Comment: If my answer is what you were looking for you can accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
df1[df1==-100] = df2
```

---

This is how it works step-by-step:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,-100,2,-100],[-100,3,-100,-100]]), columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df1

col1    col2    col3    col4
1       -100    2       -100
-100    3       -100    -100


df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[12,23,34,45],[1,2,3,4]]), columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
df2

col1    col2    col3    col4
12      23      34      45
1       2       3       4
```

By using boolean indexing you have that

```
df1==-100

col1    col2    col3    col4
False   True    False   True
True    False   True    True
```

So when `True` you can assign the corresponding value of `df2`:

```
df1[df1==-100]=df2
df1

col1    col2    col3    col4
1       23      2       45
1       3       3       4
```